# Unable to resolve class org.gradle.util.TestUtil in Gradle

Tags: testing, import, gradle, task, spock

This error means that class TestUtil is not on the classpath and the compiler can not find it. I came across such error hundred times before and there was missing Jar or wrong written class names, but now I just don't know what is wrong.
In my **buildSrc** dir I have custom Task and I made test for it:

```
package com.example.core.tasks;
import spock.lang.Specification
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.util.TestUtil

public class GetInfoTaskTest extends Specification {

    def "check files"(){
       given:
        def project = TestUtil.createRootProject()

       when:
        GetInfoTask getInfo = project.tasks.create("getInfo", GetInfoTask)

       then:
        getInfo instanceof GetInfoTask.class
    }
}
```

In the build script in the **buildSrc** dir:

```
dependencies {
compile localGroovy()

testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-1.8'
testCompile gradleApi()
```

}

Error:

```
GetInfoTaskTest.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class org.gradle.util.TestUtil
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import org.gradle.util.TestUtil     
   ^
```

I checked that this **TestUtil** is not internal. I still don't know why gradle can not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestUtil` is an internal class. You can't use it in your own code.

Comment: Is there a way to use it in my code, how to import it so Gradle to understand my that I want to use it? I know that Gradle can change its internal classes when they want.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way. You'd have to hack something together yourself. But I strongly advise against it.